# path of .properties files after build with maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

then my problem is that in my application I use several *.properties* file so in my `src/main/resources` I have my `application.properties` and in my `src/main/resources/properties` I have other *.properties* files (messages.propeties is one). and in my application I use the src/main/resources/propeties path to call my `messages.properties` file, so far all of them work. This when I make a `mvn clean install` and I deploy my *war* in a tomcat my app seems to work but when it tries to retrieve the `message.properties` file I have an **error** like `"the specified path can not be found"`. How to make sure that after making a build and deploy my war my app knows where my resource file is?

my code to read properties file:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
String valueBundle = null;
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\properties\\messages.properties");
        try {
            properties.load(input);
            valueBundle = properties.getProperty(keyBundle);
        }

        finally {
            input.close();
        }
```

Comment: share your code.. how you are reading your resource file?

Comment: How do you read the resource files? Do you get this error for all properties files or just for messages.properties? Remember, that the path to your files is relative to the "WEB-INF/classes" directory.

Comment: @kedenk i have this error for all properties files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't hard code the path.

use Classpath resources for achieving this because classloaders essentially act as a layer of abstraction between a resource name and its actual location on disk

```
public static String getMessageProperty(String code) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String value = "";
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("message.properties");
        prop.load(inputStream);
        value = prop.getProperty(code);
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below class for doing so :

```
import static java.util.Objects.nonNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;


/** This class is responsible for loading configuration from properties files.
 * @author jaikant
 *
 */
public class Config {

    // to make this singleton
        private Config() {

        }

        private static final String BASE_LOCATION = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources"
                                                    + File.separator + "properties" + File.separator;
        private static final Properties PROPERTIES = new Properties();

        static {
            loadPropertiesFile(BASE_LOCATION + "abc.properties");
            loadPropertiesFile(BASE_LOCATION + "def.properties");

            // you can have any number of properties file loaded here
        }   


        /**
         * It will load properties file
         * 
         * @param filePath
         */
        private static void loadPropertiesFile(String filePath) {
            try {
                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                PROPERTIES.load(input);
                if (nonNull(input)) {
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("!!!! Exception while loading properties file :  " +  e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        /**
         * It will give the property value present in properties file.
         * 
         * @param propertyName
         * @return property value
         */
        public static String getProperty(String propertyName) {

            return PROPERTIES.getProperty(propertyName);
        }

}
```

It will help you throughout the project for any number of properties file.
Hope that helps you.